# Text not selectable from editable DIV which is draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, jsfiddle, gridster

I build a draggable grid with [gridster](http://gridster.net/) and ran into the problem that my editable DIVs where not editable because gridster.js overrides the `click` event. I found the solution that I can manually trigger the `focus()` function when I click into the DIV, and now the text inside this DIV is changable **BUT** not selectable (not with mouse or the keyboard).

Do you know what causes this behavior? I made a JSFiddle with my code -> [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/DxsTg/1/)

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="gridster" id="frame" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">
    <ul>
        <li class="widget" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
            <div id="testID">Test 1</div>
            <div class="drag-handle">HAND</div>
        </li>
        <li class="widget" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
            <div>Test 2</div>
            <div class="drag-handle">HAND</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JS looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
        max_cols: 2,
        widget_margins: [10, 2],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 40],
        resize: {
            enabled: true,
            axes: ['x']
        },
        draggable: {
            handle: '.drag-handle'
        }
    }).data('gridster');

    $("#testID").click(function(){
          gridster.disable();
          $(this).attr("contenteditable","true");
          $(this).focus();
    })
    .blur(function(){
          gridster.enable();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Problem was the `resize` functionality. So the solution is to not just turn of the draggable() functionality when the user clicks, also you should have to turn off the `resize` function.

Turn off:

```
gridster.disable().resize_disable();
```

Turn on:

```
gridster.enable().resize_enable();
```

And I also accomplish the `editable` task now when the user double-clicks into the field, because this is a much nicer solution with less misbehaviour.